# how I can find almost the same texts?

Tags: pandas, nlp

I have a column of job postings. I want to remove almost the same texts. They are very similar to each other but they have a small differences so drop_duplications function doesn't work. I tried the following code but I like to find a better way since this one is not very accurate.
In this method I am taking 150 letter of the text and search in al of other text and find similar ones and at the end I keep one and delete all other ones.

```
bad=[]
ind=[]
ids_sub=[]
datatext=data.copy()
for i in range(datatext.shape[0]):
    datatext['originalText'].values[i]=str(datatext['originalText'].values[i]).replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('+', ' ').replace('?', ' ').replace('*', ' ').replace('|',' ').replace('-',' ').replace(':',' ').replace('@',' ')
    datatext['originalText'].values[i]=str(datatext['originalText'].values[i]).replace("\'", ' ')
    doc=datatext['originalText'].values[i][350:550]
    if len(doc)==200 and doc!=' ':
                u=datatext[datatext['originalText'].str.contains('|'.join([str(doc)]),na=False)]
                datatext=datatext[~datatext.index.isin(u[1:].index)]
                print(datatext.shape, u.shape,datatext['id'][i+1:i+2])
```

do u have a better method? How I can get almost similar text? any NLP method?

For example two following texts are almost the same:

`"Full job description\nCompany Description\n\n\nARE YOU FORGED FOR AIM RECYCLING?\n\n\nRecycles globally. Join us in our mission to recycle more than 3,000,000 tonnes of metals worldwide each year. At AIM Recycling, we recycle metals to their maximum capacity. For over 80 years, we've been working together to make a positive difference.\n\n\nBe part of our team to contribute to the growth of our company and to support our recycling activities in North America. It's simple: we do it right. We strive for excellence.\n\n\nJob Description\n\n\nUnder the supervision of Manager Asset Data Analytics, the incumbent will be responsible for supporting the deployment of data management and analytical strategies related to the asset fleet of our AIM sites (90 sites) in order to meet asset management excellence objectives.\n\n\nPosition Summary\n\n\nAnalyze data related to AIM's asset fleet to facilitate decision making related to the purchase, allocation, sale, and disposal of mobile and fixed asset in all our Recycling, Kenny and Feeder yard locations.\n\n\nMake recommendations to maximize the value of the equipment fleet and increase its operational availability.\n\n\nParticipate in the drafting of procedures or process mapping related to the mobile asset purchase, asset transfer, and asset disposal processes.\n\n\n\nAsset Maintenance Strategy:\n\nConduct useful life analysis assessment activities for the asset fleet considering asset life cycle data and failure mode patterns.\n\n\nAnalyze financial (acquisition cost, rebuild cost, NBV, depreciation) and maintenance data (cost, estimated life) related to the assets to proceed with data modeling that will include financial indicators such as PV, NPV scenarios.\n\n\nPerform a company wide asset reconciliation for high-level value assets so that the IT maintenance system (Maximo) and financial accounting system (365) reflect the field data (the physical asset inventory)\n\n\nConduct and report on internal and external maintenance cost analyses. Participate in the capital asset replacement plan.\n\n\n\nAsset monitoring_ Business Intelligence and Telematics\n\nLead and facilitate the implementation of specific programs related to the asset management for mobile fleet of heavy vehicles such as the development of daily inspection sheets via electronic tablet.\n\n\nCarry out various business intelligence and telematics projects related to assets in collaboration with the IT department. Promote the tools and ensure users support in the use of these reports and tools.\n\n\nAnalyze data and programs related to our assets in collaboration with the maintenance and finance departments.\n\n\nCollaborate in the validation and update of all site’s global assets/high-level assets register for the Recycling, Kenny and Feeder yard sites. This includes working with the Site Managers to verify/audit the assert inventory at our sites.\n\n\n\nAsset Life Cycle and Performance\n\nDevelop and maintain a set of key performance indicators and targets via business intelligence reports measuring the effectiveness of acquisition programs, asset utilization and maintenance costs for each asset category/site.\n\n\nSupport sites as needed in their asset disposal activities. Conduct asset disposition/sale activities at the appropriate time in the asset lifecycle, with the assistance of a web/auction tool.\n\n\nQualifications\n\n\n\nUniversity degree in engineering or computer science / or equivalent experience\nMaster's degree (an asset)\nSix sigma certification, process mapping (an asset)\nMinimum of 10 years of experience in data analysis/business intelligence\nKnowledge of data manipulation/programming in Advanced Excel, Macro, Pivot table, VLOOKUP\nPrevious experience in financial analysis (desirable)\nSkill in updating SharePoint content (asset) & Cognos (strong asset);\nFamiliarity with Maximo, Visio, Outlook, Excel advanced and 365.\nKnowledge of heavy equipment vehicles, fleet management (an asset)\nHave a valid driver's license.\n\nThe position requires occasional travel\n\n\nAdditional Information\n\n\n\nWorking hours:\n 40 hours/week from Monday to Friday\n\n\nPermanent position Full time Stimulating, dynamic and pleasant work environment\n\n\n\nWhat we offer:\n\nGroup insurance; Group RRSP; Free coffee; Free parking; Subsidized dinner; Gym on site; Bonus plan; Social events (BBQ, Taffy on snow, raffles, etc.).\n\n\nThe American Iron & Metal Company and its subsidiaries offer equal employment opportunities to all. The masculine is only used to lighten the text. Only those selected for an interview will be contacted."`

'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nCompany Description\nARE YOU FORGED FOR AIM RECYCLING \nRecycles globally.\nJoin us in our mission to recycle more than 3,000,000 tons of metals worldwide each year. At AIM Recyclage, we recycle metals to the maximum of their capacity. For more than 80 years, we have been working together to make a positive difference. Be part of our team to help grow our company and support our recycling activities in North America.\nIt s simple  we do it well. We strive for excellence.\nJob Description\nUnder the supervision of Manager Asset Data Analytics, the incumbent will be responsible for supporting the deployment of data management and analytical strategies related to the asset fleet of our AIM sites 90 sites in order to meet asset management excellence objectives.\nAnalyze data related to AIM s asset fleet to facilitate decision making related to the purchase, allocation, sale, and disposal of mobile and fixed asset in all our Recycling, Kenny and Feeder yard locations;\nMake recommendations to maximize the value of the equipment fleet and increase its operational availability;\nParticipate in the drafting of procedures or process mapping related to the mobile asset purchase, asset transfer, and asset disposal processes.\nAsset Maintenance Strategy\nConduct useful life analysis assessment activities for the asset fleet considering asset life cycle data and failure mode patterns;\nAnalyze financial acquisition cost, rebuild cost, NBV, depreciation and maintenance data cost, estimated life related to the assets to proceed with data modeling that will include financial indicators such as PV, NPV scenarios;\nPerform a company wide asset reconciliation for high level value assets so that the IT maintenance system Maximo and financial accounting system 365 reflect the field data the physical asset inventory;\nConduct and report on internal and external maintenance cost analyses. Participate in the capital asset replacement plan\nAsset monitoring_ Business Intelligence and Telematics \nLead and facilitate the implementation of specific programs related to the asset management for mobile fleet of heavy vehicles such as the development of daily inspection sheets via electronic tablet;\nCarry out various business intelligence and telematics projects related to assets in collaboration with the IT department. Promote the tools and ensure users support in the use of these reports and tools;\nAnalyze data and programs related to our assets in collaboration with the maintenance and finance departments;\nCollaborate in the validation and update of all site’s global assets/high level assets register for the Recycling, Kenny and Feeder yard sites. This includes working with the Site Managers to verify/audit the assert inventory at our sites.\nAsset Life Cycle And Performance\nDevelop and maintain a set of key performance indicators and targets via business intelligence reports measuring the effectiveness of acquisition programs, asset utilization and maintenance costs for each asset category/site;\nSupport sites as needed in their asset disposal activities. Conduct asset disposition/sale activities at the appropriate time in the asset lifecycle, with the assistance of a web/auction tool;\nCollaborate in value asset evaluation activity related to our new site acquisitions when required and issue asset market value for sale. Coordinate the sale process between the various sites, finance, site managers and buyers;\nParticipate in management of new requests/emails for the Asset Management team as required;\nParticipate in the planning and organization related to asset fleet for all areas of AIM and various one time projects.\nQualifications\nUniversity degree in engineering or computer science / or equivalent experience;\nMaster s degree an asset;\nSix sigma certification, process mapping an asset;\nMinimum of 10 years of experience in data analysis/business intelligence;\nKnowledge of data manipulation/programming in Advanced Excel, Macro, Pivot table, VLOOKUP;\nPrevious experience in financial analysis desirable;\nSkill in updating SharePoint content asset & Cognos strong asset;\nFamiliarity with Maximo, Visio, Outlook, Excel advanced and 365;\nKnowledge of heavy equipment vehicles, fleet management an asset;\nHave a valid driver s license.\nThe position requires occasional travel\nAdditional Information\nWorking hours40 hours/week From Monday to Friday;\nType of employment  permanent, full time.\nWhat We Offer\nGroup insurance after 3 months;\nGroup RRSP after 6 months;\nFree coffee and parking;\nSubsidized dinner;\nGym on site;\nSocial events BBQ, Snow Shoot, Draws, etc..\nThe American Iron & Metals Company and its subsidiaries offer equal employment opportunities to all. The masculine is only used to lighten the text. Only those selected for interview will be contacted.\n      \n\n\n\n        Show more\n\n        \n\n\n\n\n\n        Show less\n\n        \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n            Seniority level\n          \n\n\n\n            Associate\n          \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n          Employment type\n        \n\n\n\n          Full time\n        \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n            Job function\n          \n\n\n\n            Information Technology\n          \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n            Industries\n          \n\n\n\n          Logistics and Supply Chain, Financial Services, and Accounting\n          \n\n\n\n\n\n'

Comment: Take a look at the [`thefuzz`](https://pypi.org/project/thefuzz/) package. It's cool and will probably work here.

Comment: it's a cool package but too slow for my problem

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can use `spacy` to check sentence similarity:

**code**

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
sentence1 = "Full job description\nCompany Description\n\n\nARE YOU FORGED FOR AIM RECYCLING?"
sentence2 = "\n\n\n\Company Description\nARE YOU FORGED FOR AIM RECYCLING"

doc1, doc2 = nlp(sentence1), nlp(sentence2)

print("using spacy : {}".format(doc1.similarity(doc2)))
```

**result**

```
using spacy : 0.9444716077070359
```

Then you can work with similarity with dataframe. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sentence1' : ["Full job description\nCompany Description\n\n\nARE YOU FORGED FOR AIM RECYCLING?","Join us in our mission"],
    'sentence2' : ["\n\n\n\Company Description\nARE YOU FORGED FOR AIM RECYCLING","Reaky Relululu"]
        })

li_ = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    doc1 = nlp(df["sentence1"][i])
    doc2 = nlp(df["sentence2"][i])
    similarity = doc1.similarity(doc2)
    li_.append(similarity)
df["similarity"] = li_
df.loc[df["similarity"] > 0.8]
```

Comment: thanks but I think your loop is not correct. we need two `for` loops

Comment: also I have big texts not sentences

Comment: @user15649753 It works fine and returns similarity with your given example. and what is purpose for two `for loops`?

Comment: What is difference between doc1 and doc2? theye are both df["sentence1"][i]

Comment: @user15649753 sentence1 refers doc1, and sentence2 refers doc2